# get_terms and meta_value results blank

Tags: functions

currently, have this in my functions php

```
    $args = array (
'post_type' => 'property',
'meta_key' => 'property_channel',
'meta_value' => '1',
'orderby' => 'name',
'order' => 'ASC',
'hide_empty' => 1

 );
 $terms = get_terms("property-city", $args);
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
    <li class="calendar-filter-menu-item" data-filter=".<?php echo $term-    >slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></li>
   <?php }
  }
```

Results are blank. If i comment out meta_key and meta_value it shows the tax... but i need to show current list for property-city and meta_value 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've written a sql based function for you. By this you'll get the terms ID with slug and name by passing the parameter's as an array-

```
function the_dramatist_get_terms_with_post_meta( $args = array() ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $default_args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' => '',
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    $param = wp_parse_args( $args, $default_args );

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}terms.term_id AS terms, 
                                   {$wpdb->prefix}terms.name AS name,
                                   {$wpdb->prefix}terms.slug AS name, 
                                   {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.taxonomy AS taxonomy,
                                   COUNT({$wpdb->prefix}posts.id) AS posts
                            FROM   {$wpdb->prefix}posts 
                                   INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships 
                                           ON ( {$wpdb->prefix}posts.id = {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.object_id ) 
                                   INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy 
                                           ON ( {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 
                                                {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id ) 
                                   INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms 
                                           ON ( {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.term_id = {$wpdb->prefix}terms.term_id ) 
                                   INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS PM ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = PM.post_id)
                            WHERE  {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.taxonomy = '%s' 
                                   AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = '%s'
                                   AND (PM.meta_key = '%s' AND PM.meta_value='%s') 
                            GROUP BY terms
                            ORDER BY posts DESC",
                                array(
                                    $param['taxonomy'],
                                    $param['post_type'],
                                    $param['meta_key'],
                                    $param['meta_value'],
                                )
                            ) ;

    return $wpdb->get_results($sql);
}
```

Use this function like-

```
$terms = the_dramatist_get_terms_with_post_meta(
    array(
        'meta_key' => 'property_channel',
        'meta_value' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'taxonomy' => 'property-city'
    )
);
```

Now you'll get the data as an array of objects. You can do a `print_r` on that `$terms` variable to understand structure of the returned data of the function. The run a `for` loop or a `foreach` loop to organize the data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: They exist. If i use a loop they come up just fine but then have duplication issues with the tax. For some reason anytime i try to call the meta in anything other than a post loop its not showing. I just need a way to show a category of a custom post type that have a certain meta_value. Been at it for hours now.

Comment: Are those metas related to taxonomy ? Or they are post metas? @NoobTheory

Comment: That means you need to show a category of custom post type which's posts have this meta value ? Right ? @NoobTheory

Comment: I need a category list of the posts that contain that meta_value. Essentially  filtering down the list by taxonomy, and meta_value.

Comment: Or gather the posts that have that meta_value and make a list of the taxonomy of those posts... if that explains it better.

Comment: See my updated answer @NoobTheory

Comment: And now i feel dumb...